# Can the opposing team's goalkeeper take a kick in a penalty shootout?

Tags: rules, football, penalty-shot, goalkeeper

When doing a penalty shootout, is it possible for the opposing team's goalkeeper to take a kick? I've never seen it happen, but it seems that since the goalie is part of the team, he/she should be able to take a kick.

Bonus: Has this ever happened?

Comment: I do not know much about football but isn't there in English a word for "penalty" when they are used to decide a winner? In French there is the word "tirs au but" for that (and "penalty" is the same kick, but following a fault)

Comment: In Hockey, it is called a "shootout"

Comment: @WoJ: It's known as a penalty shootout.

Comment: Just for fun, here's an incredible goal by the goalkeeper in normal game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4u0tNcq3SGY

Comment: It's called "kicks from the penalty mark" in the rulebook, but everyone calls it a penalty shootout, because, let's face it - "kicks from the penalty mark" doesn't exactly roll off the tongue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, they can.

Example: During the 2012 UEFA Champions League final, *Manuel Neuer* of Bayern Munich took a penalty against Chelsea, when the game went into penalties.

Please refer this [wikipedia link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_UEFA_Champions_League_Final#Match_summary)

Also, when a game is being decided by penalties, then all players must have taken one penalty each, before a player can take a second penalty.
So, a goal keeper would have to take a penalty, before any other player gets a second chance.

Comment: One other memorable example I can think of is the quarter-final between Portugal and England at Euro 2004. Portugal's goalkeeper Ricardo made a save with bare hands and went on to score the deciding penalty himself.

Comment: There have been very proficient free kick and penalty takers who are goalies, such as Rogerio Ceni, Jose Luis Chilavert or the already mentioned Hans-Jörg Butt. Chilavert was also a reliable scorer as an international for Paraguay.

Comment: Wikipedia has a great article **[List of goalscoring goalkeepers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_goalscoring_goalkeepers)**. Top of the list is Rogério Ceni with a crazy 118 goals in his career (!), from penalties and free kicks mostly (all?) at club level, then José Luis Chilavert with the most international goals and who is the only keeper to score 3 in one game.

Comment: I would like to add that when one side receives a red card during the game, the other side has to appoint a player that cannot take a penalty during a penalty shootout. So, the team that is still complete has the privilege to not let their worst penalty taker shoot a penalty.

Comment: @Artyom He did that, and repeated at 2006's World Cup, again against England

Comment: I remember a certain danish goalkeeper that played for man u also scoring some famous goals.

Answer (score 30):

The [accepted answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/5191/3526) is great but I might add that in kicks from the penalty mark to decide a winner, all eligible players need to have taken a kick before a player may take a second kick.

This means that the goalkeeper not only *can* take a kick, but *must* take a kick before any of the other players take a second kick.

Comment: Regarding the first part: Except when one team is down to 10 (or less) players, then 1 (or more) player will not have to take a penalty from the other team.

Comment: @ThomasDB - yes, excess players due to send-offs or injuries from the other team will be excluded by the captain before the beginning of kicks from the penalty mark, meaning they are not eligible. I'll edit this in - thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Of course it's legal and has happened many times other than the accepted answer's example. E.g [José Luis Chilavert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Luis_Chilavert) used to take penalties that were not even in penalty shoot-outs, as well as free kicks. See: [Jose Luis Chilavert's international goals (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGAwjTizCjE).

Comment: What happens if the goal is saved and the ball goes live? Can the defending team go score without the goalie at the other end?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is legal - and as someone already claimed, even required if all other players have taken theirs.

To give some examples: Manuel Neuer converted a penalty for Bayern Munich against Real Madrid (?) in the Champions League quite recently. There are also goalkeepers who take penalties during the game, such as [Hans-Jörg Butt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans-J%C3%B6rg_Butt),  who converted a penalty for Bayern in [CL against Juventus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009%E2%80%9310_UEFA_Champions_League_group_stage#Juventus_v_Bayern_Munich). Bonus trivia: the score was 1-0 to Juventus before the penalty, which made it 1-1. Bayern went on to win 4-1.

Comment: I believe it was against Chelsea, when Neuer did a PK.

Comment: If you indeed meant the match against Chelsea, perhaps you could correct that in your post. Here is Wikipedia article about [2012 UEFA Champions League Final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_UEFA_Champions_League_Final).

Answer (score 6):

An better example than Manuel Neuer would be Jörg Butt:

"Known for taking penalty kicks, he scored 26 goals in the Bundesliga."

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans-J%C3%B6rg_Butt)

Answer (score 0):

This happened late last year in the Women's NCAA College Cup game between Rutgers University and the University of Virginia. Casey Murphy of Rutgers who was their goalkeeper shot and scored during a penalty shootout. Read more here: http://www.dailytargum.com/article/2015/11/rutgers-defeats-no-1-virginia-in-penalty-shootout-advances-to-college-cup